# Promise.all error - Type '(Video | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'Video[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise

I've got a problem with type for `Promises.all`. It supposed to return my `Video[]` interface but I got an error like

> Type '(Video | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'Video[]'.
> Type 'Video | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Video'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Video'.

when I change it into `(Video | undefined)[]` my whole typing I've got error it should have been `Video[]` again.

My code is here:

```
  const getDemo = async () => {
    setError({ show: false, msg: "" });
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const resp: Video[] = await Promise.all(
        ourData.map(async (item) => {
          if (item.type === videoConstants.TYPE_YOUTUBE) {
            return getYouTubeVideo(item.id);
          }
          if (item.type === videoConstants.TYPE_VIMEO) {
            return getVimeoVideo(item.id);
          }
        })
      );
      setData([...data, ...resp]);
    } catch {
      setError({ show: true, msg: "failed to watch demo" });
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
```

I'm using my own function to fetch API to keep rules of "DRY" - when I fetch a single object is okay, but when I use for `Promise.all` to get all collection from our DataBase I've got an error I cannot handle with.

Comment: Any reason you're running an `async` function in map? `ourData.map(async (item)...`

Comment: does `getYouTubeVideo` return a promise? If so, you'll need to either `await` that before the return so your `async` function returns real data instead of a promise, or you need to make your map function not be async, since it's already returning a promise. (async functions are just regular functions that return promises, without you having to write all the pomise code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below:

```
if (item.type === videoConstants.TYPE_YOUTUBE) {
  return getYouTubeVideo(item.id);
}
if (item.type === videoConstants.TYPE_VIMEO) {
  return getVimeoVideo(item.id);
}
```

will have return type as `Video | undefined` because there is no `else` block.

You can try this (if `item.type` can only take the two values present in `videoConstants`):

```
if (item.type === videoConstants.TYPE_YOUTUBE) {
  return getYouTubeVideo(item.id);
}
return getVimeoVideo(item.id);
```

or maybe:

```
if (item.type === videoConstants.TYPE_YOUTUBE) {
  return getYouTubeVideo(item.id);
}
if (item.type === videoConstants.TYPE_VIMEO) {
  return getVimeoVideo(item.id);
}
return {} as Video // TODO: depends on Video
```

or if you can do none of the above, this maybe your last option - `const resp: (Video|undefined)[] = ...`

Comment: What if his `item.type` is always either `videoConstants.TYPE_YOUTUBE` or `videoConstants.TYPE_VIMEO`? In which case an `else` wouldn't be necessary. Are you saying his code would work?

Comment: Dude, thank you! It really works! :D I was spending a on this case couple of hours. I'm a newbie in Typescript and suddenly started working with Typescript in my company, and you have saved my life. Thank you one more time! :)

Comment: @codemonkey I don't know all the possible values of `item.type`. But if there are only **two** possible values then **one** `if` and **no else, but direct return** should work.

Comment: @๖JoJo haha. Happy to help :) Make sure to test your code when `item.type` is `videoConstants.TYPE_VIMEO`.

Comment: I checked right now, everything works smoothly :D I'm gonna learn more TypeScript really liked these all interfaces and the way of working (really hard to create an app with the bug)